# PHP - Finding number of matching words between two pieces of text?

Tags: php, match, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-logic

I want to find number of similar words between two texts

**Example**

```
$str1=the cat is on the roof  
$str2=the mouse is on the roof
```

**the,is,on,the,roof** words are similar in $str1 and $str2

So  output will be  **in number 5** OR  **In percentage 86%**

I am try similar_text() function but this function not work as which i want.

Comment: Hey, the code ran away, go and get it, hurry!

Comment: How did you get 86%? There are 12 words total and 10 are matches and that gives 83% - where does the extra 3% come from?

Comment: And `similar_text` provides 83% as well, sure looks right to me

Comment: @jszobody If I am change word sequence thn output comes different try this string............  str1="the cat is on the roof"  $str2= "the on the roof mouse is"

Comment: I suggest string tokenizer. http://php.net/strtok

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy, explode them and then use array_diff:

```
$totalWords = count($array_1);

$array_1 = explode(" ", $str1);
$array_2 = explode(" ", $str2);
$differenceCount = count(array_diff($array_1, $array_2));

$differentPercent = $differenceCount / ($totalWords / 100);
```

@Edit:

Edited code above to display percentage. However remember you may have a wrong result if the word count of array 1 and array 2 is not identical.

Comment: thnx @Steini for giving answer ...can possible to check how much percentage of words similar between two string...

Comment: I am try edited code....display operand error : <b> error Unsupported operand types</b>

Comment: I forgot a ; at the end of the code, updated it however you should know a little about coding / errorhandling before asking such questions. This site is to give solution hints, not completely working systems.

Comment: thnx steini ...it working now ...but wrong result display.....try this two string  $str1 = 'make higher the  USA  pie'; 
 $str2 = 'make higher pie the USA'; Output : 28.571428571429 %

Comment: steini PLZ update your answer with change 2nd last line :  $differenceCount = count(array_diff($arr1, $arr2));

Comment: @Up oh, my bad thanks yea you are right forgot to count the array :S

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr1 = explode(" ",$str1)
$arr2 = explode(" ",$str2)

$arr3 = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);

echo(count($arr1)-count($arr3));
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach this is to explode each string and then use `array_diff` to compare them like this:

```
$arr1 = explode(' ', $str1);
$arr2 = explode(' ', $str2);
$diff = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
echo (count($arr1) - count($diff));
```

That will echo out the number of similar words.

Comment: There are 2 almost identical answers already, was that really nesessary?

Comment: @steini They weren't there when I typed my answer, look at the times, really close. There were no answers when I started.

Comment: Fine I remove it but still you can click the refresh button before sending the post There are 3 minutes between existing posts and yours...

Comment: Hi Steini and @Styphon ...........can possible to check how much percentage of words similar between two string

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = explode(" ",$str1)
$arr2 = explode(" ",$str2)

$arr3 = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
```

i used array_intesect to check how many matches,, i used this in searching
one array into other

and for preventing with auxilary verbs and prepositions(the,to,a,are etc)
use -

```
$arr1 = str_replace(array("to", "the","a","an","in","by","but","are","is","had","have","has"),'',$arr1);
```