# count number of words matched in a string

Tags: php

I have two Strings. Both seems similar but one of them is the main String and the other is the Finde String.

For Example:

```
 $MainString = 'Yellow Green Orange Blue Yellow Black White Purple';
 $FinderString = 'Yellow Blue White';
```

My Question now is how to split those Strings in to an Array to check each one with the other one of the other string?

Here is my Tryed code:

```
<?php
   $MainString = 'Yellow Green Orange Blue Yellow Black White Purple';
   $FinderString = 'Yellow Blue White';
   $resault = substr_count($MainString, $FinderString);
   echo("number of matched colores: ".$resault);
?>
```

Resault of my Code:

```
number of matched colores: 0
```

My expection of this Code:

```
number of matched colores: 4
```

Can some one pleas help me to fix this?

--- FINAL CODE AFTER HELP: ---

Now I wrote this code it's not the best I guess but he works.

```
<?php
    $MainString = 'Yellow Green Orange Blue Yellow Black White Purple';//declare the main String
    $FinderString = 'Yellow Blue White'; //declare the finder String
    $MainlyString = explode(" ",$MainString); //splitting the massive string into an Array.
    $FindlyString = explode(" ",$FinderString); //splitting the massive string into an Array.
    $resault = 0; //declare the counters


    foreach($MainlyString as $main) { //running through the Array and give the result an Alias.
        foreach($FindlyString as $find) { //runing through the Array and gave the resault an Alias.
            if (substr_count($main, $find) == 1) { //Checking if a month is matching a mother.
                $resault = $resault + 1; //increase the counter by one 
            }
        }
    }

    echo("number of matched month: ".$resault."<br>"); //output of the counter
?>
```

Thanks for the help guys. :)

Comment: you could explode the needle first, then use each exploded piece in a loop and just apply substring count function. a simple counter and `+=` should suffice

Comment: @Ghost a few seconds earlier than me xD

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/21164358/6309457

Comment: ups sorry @DevsiOdedra Stack Overflow does not show this to me I don't know why... sorry for dupe...

Comment: you can apply your current code using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21164498/3859027

Comment: `You can do something like that

    $string = "Yellow Green Orange Blue Yellow Black White Purple";
    $FinderString = 'Yellow Blue White';
    
    $words = explode(' ', $FinderString);
    
    $count = 0;
    foreach($words as $word) {
       if(substr_count($string, $word)){
          $count += substr_count($string, $word);
           
      }
    }
    
    echo $count;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello PassCody first of all wellcome on Stackoverflow.

In this case you can split/explode the String into a separate Array to single check the colores.

For this you can use the PHP function explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] ) returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

Here is an Example:

```
<?php
   $colors = "Yellow Green Orange Blue Yellow Black White Purple";
   $colors = explode(" ", $colors);
   echo $colors[0]; // color 1
   echo $colors[1]; // color 2
?>
```

Comment: Try it.
`code`$MainString = explode(" ",$MainString);
`code`$FinderString = explode(" ",$FinderString);
`code`echo $containsSearch = count(array_intersect($FinderString , $MainString ));

Comment: @BhaveshPatel your code is counting the array index numbers. For his expectation you should set `+ 1` at the end of your count function. ;)